# knex transaction not working in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, loopbackjs, knex.js

I'm using knex in loopback for DB operation with mysql.
My task is to update the 2 table by using the transaction.
When I enter new entry in one tabe, i want to use id of that entry for 2nd query operation.

But when transaction throw the error it not rolling back the data/ removing the first table entry if second table entry throws error. but in my case transaction always do commit not rollback i put my example code in below:

```
addTest : (data) => {
  return new promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    knex.transaction(function(t) {
       return knex('foo')
       .transacting(t)
       .insert({
          foo_id: data.foo_id ? data.foo_id : null,
          foo_name: data.foo_name ? data.foo_name : null,
          date_entered : new Date()
        })
       .then(function() {
          return knex('bar')
          .transacting(t)
          .insert({
            bar_id: data.bar_id ? data.bar_id : null,
            bar_name : data.bar_name ? data.bar_name : null
          })

       })
       .then(t.commit) 
        .catch(function(e) {
          t.rollback();
          throw e;
        })      
    })
    .then(function() {
     // it worked
     // resolve('sucess');
     console.log('success');
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
     // it failed
     console.log('error'+e);
    }); 
  });
}
```

please, provide me suitable suggestion.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid having to call `t.commit` or `t.rollback` youself. See [the docs](http://knexjs.org/#Transactions).

Make your code inside the transaction function something like this

`return t.insert({}).into('foo').returning('id')
   .then( function(idArray) {
    return t.insert({fooId: idArray[0]}).into('bar')
   })`

That lets knex handle the commiting and rolling back itself based on the result result of that promise. Also, note how I got the inserted `fooId` and applied it to the `bar` object for `insert`ion. That was kind of mentioned in the question.

Comment: Your undefined binding is because a column is not in your db; the query cannot insert. All the rest is hard to understand without seeing the code you are using to get that error (and the definition of your DB tables)

Comment: As per the docs, if `knex.transaction(function(t) {` returns a Promise (like yours does), it will automatically call `t.commit` and `t.rollback` based on the resolution of that promise. Your code calling it as well is likely the cause of your problem (beyond the undefined binding and not using the first inserted id in your second query). Either call `t.commit` `t.rollback` yourself and do not return a promise, or return a promise chain and let Knex handle the resolution of the transaction.

Comment: `.returning() is not supported by mysql and will not have any effect.` as per the docs, returning('id') in mysql will not work